# Gitlab - update configuration for use with redmine and redeploy

Tags: redmine, gitlab, redmine-plugins

I want to start using Redmine with Gitlab for issue tracking.

Is there a way to update the gitlab configuration (gitlab.yml) with the redmine urls and start using both applications without having to bundle Gitlab again?

Comment: What do you mean by "bundle GitLab"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly.

There is a Redmine plugin which does the opposite: "[Gitlab Merge Request](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_gitlab_merge_request)"

> This plugin allow you to add a "New merge request" link on redmine issue.
>   Gitlab merge request form will be filled based on project configuration

And there is a (closed) feature request [issue 97](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/97) asking for using Redmine is recommended for Issue management (again the opposite of what you are asking for)

However, this [feedback request](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3909401-redmine-issue-integration) is closer:

> > I currently use Redmine for my issues in oreder to do time-tracking, gantt, versions, guest access.
> >     I think it would be cool to allow setup for Redmine issues to be synced into Gitlab and possibly vice versa.
>
> You can now link Redmine issues from GitLab: see [`gitlab.yml.example`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5ec3129ea657dc1c28c45ed4f54ec62fc6050ce6/config/gitlab.yml.example#L54).

```
  ## External issues trackers
  issues_tracker:
    # redmine:
    #   title: "Redmine"
    #   ## If not nil, link 'Issues' on project page will be replaced with this
    #   ## Use placeholders:
    #   ##  :project_id        - GitLab project identifier
    #   ##  :issues_tracker_id - Project Name or Id in external issue tracker
    #   project_url: "http://redmine.sample/projects/:issues_tracker_id"
```

So it doesn't *replace* Redmine issue management with GitLab's, but it helps keeping the two in sync.